# Installing magento on localhost server

Tags: magento-1.9, html, jquery, magento-1.9.2.1

I am trying to install Magento on my localhost server.

I have downloaded magento full version from the http://www.magento.com/download and have got all the files from there running in my project, from here I went to the URL (http://localhost/magento/magento/index.php/install (need the 2x magento as it is a VS project and that's just how they do it for some reason)) and I have got the screen, but from there is it throwing an error in the console saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I know this is a jQuery error, but for some reason it's not in place. I have added the jQuery libraries in (not sure if it is the right one (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`)) and this gave me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setStyle is not a function

This is also the case when using the latest jQuery

Can anyone help me to figure this out/fix this so I can get magento to run please?

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, I am new to this and would appreciate the help :)

Comment: I see you've added the Magento2 tag. Is this Magento 2? Please clearly state this in your question as Magento 1 uses prototype.js which will conflict with jQuery and you'll get a lot of responses stating this if people missed out that this question is actually about Magento2.

Comment: @7ochem Odd, I never added the 2.x tag?? I am using v1.9.2.1

Comment: Another user added the tag...